# Android make TextView and Button text style match

Tags: android

I have a Button and TextView next to each other and I am wanting the text style to match.
The first image has no modifications to text styling on each (minus setting textSize to 16sp), second picture is setting the TextView style bold.

I am looking for a way to get the weight/style of both Button and TextView to match.

[image: TextView/Button1]
[image: TextView/Button2]

Comment: I don't think anyone would understand you at all. What do you mean by 'make text styles match'. Which of them is the button, I can't see any button. Please provide a clear description or a clear visual representation of the problem you are facing

Comment: If I understood you correctly and by matching, you mean you want to have a single style you can apply to both the TextView and Button. Just use the `style` attribute in the XML layout file to do that. Then in styles.xml, you can add a custom style you can apply to both of them

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can replace the button with a textview and add a clickListener to the textView.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).